# Attatch debugger to Android Device not working in Netbeans (not emulator)

Tags: java, android, debugging, netbeans

I cant seem to attach the debugger when trying to execute my code on Galaxy 2 T989. I am using Netbeans with the standard Android development plugin.

When I try to attach the debugger, the dialog pops up in netbeans. There is no device shown (I am guessing its defaulting to my phone since it lets me select the process. I select the process (Not shown in the image), but when I try to click on ok, it does absolutely nothing. The dialog stays open and nothing changes. My phone still shows "Waiting for Debugger".

```
 //cant post image as I don't have enough points
```

I would much prefer to debug off my phone because I am dealing with sockets and would rather have real world simulation of the data being transferred. I am using 4.0.3 SDK, code runs fine on my 2.3.5 on my phone, I have not tried it on my Prime yet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZTeY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those coming by to solve this issue, I found the solution. Its quite simple. Go into your plugins menu from tools. After you have done that, go into the installed tab and make sure your "User Installed Plugins" is marked as "active" (make sure the circle is green)

Comment: This does not sound very convincing to me (I am author of NBAndroid plugin). You had the plugin activated when took the screenshot because the project type is recognized. My guess is that there was a problem with ADB bridge that did not see your device. http://www.nbandroid.org/2011/07/how-to-fix-broken-communication-with.html can help.

Answer (score 0):

1) install usb_driver

2) set your device option on USB debugging

Comment: The driver is installed properly. The app gets pushed to it just fine.

Comment: have you attached your device to keyboard's USB?

Comment: some times long USB cable can causes problems

Comment: Using standard USB cable which comes with the device. Connected to the USB in the back of the machine. USB is 2.0. Once again, application gets put onto the phone properly.

Comment: The app wont get pushed to the phone if I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using ddms as a bridge between the device an netbeans.
You have to configure a local debugger port in ddms and make your netbeans connect to that port using a regular java debugger.
I have written a [tutorial article on my blog.](http://mindstack.de/2013/11/04/debugging-android-apps-on-device-with-netbeans/)

Comment: Try to include the key points from an external resource incase the link dies in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Phone Settings:**

Settings->"Developer Options"->"Select USB Configuration" 
Select MIDI from the List.

**Netbeans Settings**

Options->HTML/JS Tab->Mobile Platforms->Android SDK Location must be also selected correctly
Android SDK Location is often:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk